# How to ls without recursive

Tags: bash, shell-script, ls

I am trying to ls some files with a pattern in a directory. I only want to scan the first level not recursive.

My script:

```
for i in $(ls $INCOMINGDIR/*$BUSSINESSDATE*)
do
  echo $i;
done
```

Above command scan recursively. How can make it only to scan the first level directory?

Comment: `printf %s\\n "$INCOMINGDIR/"*"$BUSINESSDATE"*`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Also [don't use ALL_CAPS_VARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552)

```
for i in "$incoming_dir"/*"$business_date"*; do
```

Interactively, `ls` has a `-d` option that prevents descending into subdirectories:

```
ls -d $INCOMINGDIR/*$BUSSINESSDATE*
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am going to start creating files with new lines in the name just to annoy sysadmins now.

Comment: That's why the smart sysadmin/programmer uses `"${i}"`. You never know what might be in `i`.

Comment: @Petah: or someone with bad intentions could create a file named `my_file.doc[newline]another_persons_file.doc` and hope that some scripts may try to "rm" what it sees as 2 filenames... Glenn's link is a must read (on mywiki.wooledge.org, everyone should read the whole faq, and also the pitfalls page)

Comment: cool. i didn't know the -d option!

Comment: Great! This works for simpler things too. Such as list all dot-prefixed files: `ls -d .*`

Answer (score 8):

There is no reason why this command should be recursive. But if `$INCOMINGDIR/*$BUSSINESSDATE*` matches a directory then the content of this directory is shown instead of the directory itself. But there would be no recursion beyond this level.

Use this command to avoid that effect:

```
ls -d "$INCOMINGDIR/"*"$BUSSINESSDATE"*
```

`for ... in` commands with `ls` output are risky.

In general `find` seems a better solution or

```
for i in "$INCOMINGDIR/"*"$BUSSINESSDATE"*
```